# CSS Float doesn't work? Why?

Tags: html, css, css-float, styling, point

So I am currently creating a website and I have a problem. I have this div, and in the left top corner of it I want a facebook like button, and then I want text to surround it, I know this can be fixed through the "float" property, but it just won't work, instead, the text which I want to surround the facebook like button goes under the button and there is a huge space left to the right of the button..

This is my code:

```
<p>
    <div class="float">
        <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=www.mysite.com&amp;send=false&amp;layout=box_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;font=arial&amp;height=90" scrolling="no" frameborder="1" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:90px;" allowTransparency="true">
        </iframe>
    </div> 
    test
</p>
```

The css code is

```
div.float{
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the CSS code for that float class?

Comment: It doesn't work, when I paste in the code it's gone.

Comment: Please show some code. Use the code button (`{}`) to indent it properly

Comment: Please add what your CSS code for the class .float looks like

Comment: Can you provide the css definitions? edit: lol

Comment: @Kevin that is not correct syntax. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/float

Comment: Yeah, I wrote wrong, it is div.float{ float:left; }

Comment: @Kevin change `div.float{ position:float; }` to div.float{ float:left; }` (or right, if that's where you want it to go)

Comment: It is already float:left; , i wrote wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this solution:

```
.float{
    float: left;
    width: 70px;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j9QSj/

Let me know if it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a clear: both on the next div or span down. You can share your code with http://www.pastebin.com/.

Comment: Yes, you will need to create a div or span below it with a style of clear:both to cancel the float for the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The width of the iframe is 450px... you probably meant it to be 45px
in the url change width=450 to width=45 that should fix your problem.

Comment: you have to add width:45px; to the style of your div too

Answer (score -1):

The css definition is wrong.

It needs to be

```
float:left
```

instead of

```
position:float
```